# Cannot load web api method using Backbone.js

Tags: c#, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a blank asp.net solution with 5 different projects. One of them is asp.net web api and other one is blank web site with bunch of html pages. I am using backbone.js/jQuery to make calls to the web api within the solution. My blank web site is running on different port and my web api is running on different port.

```
//Collection
var AuditsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: 'http://localhost:56501/api/searchaudits',

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
                if (!options.crossDomain) {
                    options.crossDomain = true;
                }

                options.timeout = 1000;
                alert(method + ": " + JSON.stringify(model));
                return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
            },
});
var audits = new AuditsCollection();

// Model
var Audit = Backbone.Model.extend({ });
var audit = new Audit({ auditNumber: "A12" });

audits.add(audit);
```

// POST CALL - I am sending this model and expecting back another JSON object in response.

```
 audit.save({}, {

    success: function (response) {
        alert("Got audits successfully" + response);
    },
    error: function (response) {

        alert("Error.. Go home now");
    }
});
```

I still get this error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://mydomain:56501/api/searchaudits`. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: Do you get a useful result by browsing to the same URL via the address bar?

Comment: Yes, it's a POST, so when I make a POST call using Fiddler I get response back.

Comment: But your code isn't attempting to POST, because you're calling auditsCollection.fetch.  Am I missing something here?  Can you attempt to breakpoint your WebAPI project, or run elmah to see what's happening server-side?

Comment: Good catch, I updated my code and now I am getting the following

OPTIONS http://localhost:56501/api/searchaudits 405 (Method Not Allowed) 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load /api/searchaudits. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what the issue is. The project is setup in the following structure.

**Error:**

-- Solution

```
-- Project 1 (Web API) - running on `http://localhost:80/api`

-- Project 2

-- Project 3

-- Project 4 (Views) - running on `http://localhost:3000/`
```

So when I started making ajax requests, it started giving exceptions like

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:80/api/searchaudits`. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.**

**OPTIONS `localhost:80/api/searchaudits` 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load /api/searchaudits**

I did not know that it is going to consider domains with different ports ad different domains.

Solution:

Override Backbone.Sync method - [reference](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/10/29/overriding-backbone-js-sync-to-allow-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/)

In your Web Api projects web.config file, add the following

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

There are answers in StackOverflow regarding this issue in bits and pieces, but this is an effort to put the complete solution together in one place.